RPi and systemd not booting into programme
I am working outdoors where using a monitor in the field is awkward and unweieldy for a number of reasons.
I require my raspberry pi 4 to run a headless programme on power-on/boot, which would read a number of sensors via the 4 USB ports and save that to a file on SD card. I'm using systemd which I've reloaded and enabled using systemctl. Prog won't run on boot but will run if I start the service from the terminal.
Unit file is:-
Description = reading sensors


Service is :-
Type = idle
User = pi
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/sensors/readsensors.py
Restart = always

Install is:-
WantedBy = usb-gadget.target
WantedBy =multiuser.target
Wanted By =boot-complete.target

I have tried including systemctl restart service sensor in the body of the service file but no difference.

Are you running Ubuntu on the Pi? If so, what version?

I'm using python

What is the Operating System running on the computer?

The user = pi suggests you are using Raspberry Pi OS. Please edit your question and add the distro and version of Linux you are using in your Pi.
